# Como pegar a assinatura de métodos alterados em um commit

Tags: git, método, commit, diff

Então pessoal, eu preciso da assinatura de todos os métodos que foram alterados em um commit, seja atualizado, removido ou adicionado.

Exemplo:
[Neste commit](https://github.com/fladson/SamplePathCoverage/commit/dd8c69f7ed581888292874d26e7b245a71b11f50)

Os métodos alterados foram:

```
 - br.ufrn.ase.Classe1.metodoB(int b)U
 - br.ufrn.ase.Classe1.getV()D
 - br.ufrn.ase.Classe1.metodoadicionado()A
 - br.ufrn.ase.Classe2.metodoQualquer(int i)A
 - br.ufrn.ase.Classe2.outro(int j)A
```

Alguém tem ideia de como fazer isso ou sabe de alguma lib que já faça? O código de acessar os commits e pegar o blob eu já tenho.
Estou desenvolvendo em Java, mas a lib pode ser em qualquer linguagem.

Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver esse problema usando a seguinte combinação:

- Com um git blame entre o commit desejado e o seu parent eu consigo extrair quais linhas foram modificadas e pego os respectivos números das linhas;
- Implementei um JDT Parser (usando AST.JLS8) que faz o parse dos arquivos modificados armazenando a linha inicial e final de cada método declarado;
- Daí é só passar o número da linha modificada obtida no passo 1 e procurar dentro do range dos métodos obtidos no passo 2.

Não consegui um bom resultado com esse exemplo do Pedro, alguns retornaram o pacote da classe no lugar da assinatura do método.

Answer (score 0):

GIT já identifica, quando possível, o método que foi modificado.

Basta lançar o comando:

```
git show $COMMIT
```

Para filtrar melhor o resultado pode ser por linha de comando (via linux)

```
git show $COMMIT | grep @@ | sed 's/@@.*@@//g'
```

Este comando procura pelos arrobas, indicando a mudança, depois remove o começo da linha que contem o range de linhas modificados.

Em windows, voce pode fazer a primeira parte com FINDSTR.

Estou usando git v2.4.0.